# How do you prove this

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A\sim B$, then $\mathcal P \left({A}\right) \sim \mathcal P \left({B}\right)$.

I am so lost how to even start proving this. I don't understand equinumerosity whatsoever.

Comment: What definition are you working with for the relation $\sim$? Is it the existence of a bijection between sets $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 0):

Pick a bijection $f:A\rightarrow B$.  Now consider the map $E\mapsto f(E)$ that takes ${\mathcal P}(A)$ to ${\mathcal P}(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A \sim B$ (i.e. there exists some bijection between $A$ and $B$), then $|A| = |B|$.

You also know that for some set $X$, $|P(X)| = 2^{|X|}$.

Consequently, $P(A) = P(B)$.

And given that these two sets are the same size, you can construct an arbitrary bijection between them (e.g. just enumerate and match the members).

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question but I didn't find a suitable answer when I was looking for it so I propose my solution for others looking for one.

---

*Proof:* Since $A\sim B$, we can be certain we have a function $f:A\to B$,
such that $f$ is bijective. Our goal is to find a bijective function
$g:\mathcal{P}(A)\to \mathbb{P}(B)$, let us define $g$ by the
following:
\begin{equation*}
    g(X) = f(X) =  \{f(x)\vert x\in X\}
\end{equation*}
Here $f(X)$ is the image of $X$ under the function $f$. Now we aim
to prove that $g$ is injective and surjective to show bijectivity.
Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two arbitrary element of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and
suppose that $g(X_1)=g(X_2)$, we aim to show that this implies that
$X_1 = X_2$, let us suppose for the sake of contradiction that
$X_1\neq X_2$ and with out loss of generality assume that $x\in X_1$
but $x\notin X_2$. $f(x)\in X_1$ so $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $y\in X_2$,
since $f$ is injective $x=y$ and thus $x\in X_2$ which is a
contradiction so in conclusion $X_1 = X_2$, this shows that $f$ is at
least injective.

Let $Y$ be a arbitrary element of $\mathcal{P}(B)$, since
$Y\in\mathcal{P}(B)$ we know that $Y\subseteq B$. Thus since $f$ is
surjective onto $B$, for every element $y$ in $Y$ there is some
$x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$, then if we take all those element in
$A$ and form the set $X =\{a\in A\vert \exists y\in
Y(f(a)=y)\}\subseteq A$, and since $g(X) = Y$ we can state that $g$
is surjective

Thus $g:\mathcal{P}(A)\to \mathbb{P}(B)$ as we defined it, is
injective and surjective, or rather bijective and thus
$\mathcal{P}(A)\sim \mathbb{P}(B)$. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

This answer might be incomplete and is open to critique, I didn't want to post a replicate question. (The subjectivity part might especially be written clearer I feel.)